# NSInputStream freezes app after opening stream in iOS6

Tags: ios, multithreading, networking, grand-central-dispatch, nsstream

I am using NSInputStream to grab some resources from web like this:

```
CFHTTPMessageRef request = CFHTTPMessageCreateRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, CFSTR("GET"), (__bridge CFURLRef)url, kCFHTTPVersion1_1);
CFReadStreamRef readStream = CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest(kCFAllocatorDefault, request);
CFRelease(request);

_inputStream = CFBridgingRelease(readStream);
_inputStream.delegate = self;
[_inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[_inputStream open];
```

And then to offload the actual work to other thread:

```
- (void)stream:(NSStream *)aStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)eventCode
{
    NSLog(@"stream: %@ handleEvent: %d", aStream, eventCode);
    dispatch_async(_custom_serial_queue, ^{

        switch(eventCode) {
            case NSStreamEventOpenCompleted: {
                NSLog(@"Stream has opened");
                break;
            }
            // rest of switch
    });
}
```

I see *Stream has opened* log and then in 95% of cases my main thread freezes

[image: Screenshot of call stack of main thread]

This happens only on iPhone4 and iOS6.1, on iPhone5s and iOS7 and iPad3 iOS6.1 everything is fine.

Could you please suggest what is wrong with this code.

EDIT 1: I have tracked down problem to some piece of code(in 3rd party lib) which uses `__sync_add_and_fetch` function. It seems it causes the issue but I still need to use it.

EDIT 2: I have changed `__sync_add_and_fetch` function by `OSAtomicAdd32` but it hasn't changed anything.

EDIT 3: I have checked the problem on other devices. Works fine on iPhone4s iOS7, iPad2 iOS6.1. It seems the problem is only relevant to 1 core devices.

Comment: Is that `CFRelease(request);` right?  (I haven't looked at the reference, but it looks wrong to me).

Comment: Hmm, yes but I don't see the problem there. It is created with retain count 1, passed to `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest` which I assume retains it and then released after that. Do I miss something?

Comment: I'm not sure, however the docs for `CFReadStreamCreateForHTTPRequest()` don't state that it retains the request and none of the Apple sample code I've looked at release it there either.  Something to look into in more detail.

Comment: I have commented it out, but the problem persists. I don't think it is relevant.

Comment: Thanks anyway. I have now even tried to replace OSAtomicAdd32 with plain non atomic add, but the problem is still there. :(

Comment: OK next things: 1) it looks like you are using XPC and it's stuck waiting for the reply from the XPC service... can you explain what you do with XPC?  2) Doesn't the stream need a runloop to operate?  How does that work using a *non-main-dispatch-queue*?

Comment: OK. 1) I don't do anything specific. As you can see it is called from SCNetworkReachability. 2) I only read stream buffers from another thread/queue. The stream itself is in main runloop. I can't see immediate problems with that beside buffer corruption (maybe)

Comment: Ah OK.  I would be tempted to dump `NSStream` in favour of GCDAsyncSocket, but of course that might take some work.